# SQL to find the distribution of monthly frequency of customers for the year 2022

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction table with transaction_id and customer_id and date of transaction as transaction_date.  I want to find distribution of monthly frequency of customers for the year 2022. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to data science and analytics.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result as tables with text in your question. Also explain what you have tried and what exactly did not work as expected. Keep in mind SO is no code writing service.

Comment: share your tried query

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
SELECT MONTH([date])
      ,COUNT(customer_id) -- customers per month
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) -- unique customers per month
FROM [transaction]
WHERE YEAR([date]) = 2022
GROUP BY MONTH([date])
```

the above will give you the total of customers per months. And if you need to drill down and find the transactions for each customer per month:

```
SELECT customer_id
      ,MONTH([date])
      ,COUNT(transaction_id)
FROM [transaction]
WHERE YEAR([date]) = 2022
GROUP BY customer_id
```